# How to integrate multiple service providers into Paypal app?

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I want to create an app in the future that uses the paypal API. The app will allow different service providers to offer their services and allow clients to pay through my app. I've looked at the SDK and I don't see anywhere to dynamically insert the service provider's email or merchant id.

Is this possible? If so, can you please direct me to an example?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you have lots of options for how to handle it.  You could use Express Checkout, Payments Pro, Adaptive Payments, etc.  Depending on exactly what your goal is you may or may not need to use one instead of another.  I personally prefer Express Checkout whenever possible.

Comment: I want a provider to sign up for my app and somewhere in their profile add an email or merchant id. Then, when a client wants to purchase their services, I dynamically fill the API call with that information. In other words, I don't want to compile a separate app for each provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Express Checkout, and you don't even have to mess with Permissions at all, so that's what I would recommend.

Within the SetExpressCheckout request you can include a value for SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID.  This would be the email address or merchant ID of the user that you want the money to go to.  If you  have that value in your user's data, then all you need to do is include it as the value for that parameter when you generate a payment request and the money will go to that account.

Comment: Thank you for your response I will look into Express Checkout.

Comment: Are you building native Android apps, or would you be working with PHP web services, by chance?  If you happen to be working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) would make the API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: I have not yet decided on how to do the calls. I'm still in the research phase.